# Delete query is not working with order by for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE1
(
     CN VARCHAR(MAX),
     CR VARCHAR(MAX), 
     DN VARCHAR(MAX),
     DR VARCHAR(MAX),
     DMR VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO SAMPLE1 VALUES ('C1', 'A', 'D1', '--', '--')
INSERT INTO SAMPLE1 VALUES ('C1', 'B', 'D1', '-A', '--')
INSERT INTO SAMPLE1 VALUES ('C1', 'E', 'D2', '--', '--')
INSERT INTO SAMPLE1 VALUES ('C1', 'C', 'D1', '-A', '--')
INSERT INTO SAMPLE1 VALUES ('C1', 'D', 'D3', '--', '--')
INSERT INTO SAMPLE1 VALUES ('C1', 'F', 'D2', '--', '--')
INSERT INTO SAMPLE1 VALUES ('C1', 'F', 'D2', '-A', '--')
```

Expected result:

```
('C1', 'F', 'D2', '-A', '--')
```

i.e last record from SAMPLE1.

I tried with the following query, but it doesn't work:

```
DELETE t
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CN
                           ORDER BY CR, DR, DMR DESC) AS r
     FROM SAMPLE1) t
WHERE r > 1
```

Comment: SQL Server @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? Unexpected results? Undesired behaviour? Some else entirely?

Comment: This is a dangerous practice, consider adding a unique id to the table or insert time

Comment: You wanted to specify `desc` on each column in the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using SQL Server, you could place the logic from your current query into a deletable CTE:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CN
                                 ORDER BY CR DESC, DR DESC, DMR DESC) rn
    FROM SAMPLE1
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: I want last record ('C1','F','D2','-A','--') with your query  i am getting ('c1','A','D1','--','--')

Comment: Sorry...I guess your original `ORDER BY` logic was off.  Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: The code in their question is using a deletable derived table which is also valid and behaves the same as a deletable CTE

Comment: @MartinSmith For background, it wasn't clear to me whether the OP had a syntax problem, or whether the code ran but with a wrong result.  I assumed the former.